# How to fill columns based on other column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df where I want to query the postalcode to match address and city.

```
Postalcodestring
1181
1055
8547
```

I'm using nomi.query_postal_code('n') for this. Hereby, when inputting the following the table is shown:

```
postal_code                1181
country_code                 NL
place_name           Amstelveen
state_name        Noord-Holland
state_code                    7
county_name          Amstelveen
county_code                 362
community_name              NaN
community_code              NaN
latitude                  52.31
longitude                4.8631
accuracy                      6
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I want to fill the city and country for the column 'City1' and 'Country1' to fill each row of postal code. When a postalcode is n/a, I want the row City1 and Country1 to be N/A too!

I have tried the following code:

```
#NL
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, 'City1'] = nomi.query_postal_code(df['Postalcodestring'][i])[2]    
#DE
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i,'City2'] = nomi2.query_postal_code(df['Postalcodestring'][i])[2]

#NLCountry
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i,['Country1']] = nomi.query_postal_code(df['Postalcodestring'][i])[1]    
#DECountry
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i,'Country2'] = nomi2.query_postal_code(df['Postalcodestring'][i])[1]
```

However, getting the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-d0d96a6ea61b> in <module>
     67 #NL
     68 for i, row in df.iterrows():
---> 69     df.loc[i, 'City1'] = nomi.query_postal_code(df['Postalcodestring'][i])[2]
     70 #DE
     71 for i, row in df.iterrows():
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Desired output:

```
Postalcodestring   City1 
1181               Amstelveen
1055               Amsterdam
8547               NaN
```

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `df.apply` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import pgeocode

df = pd.DataFrame({'Postalcodestring': ['1181', '1055', '8547']})
nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim('nl')

df['City1'] = df['Postalcodestring'].apply(lambda code: nomi.query_postal_code(code)['place_name'])
```

There is really no need to loop over the rows individually, when you can use `df[COL].apply` instead, to apply a function to every row of a column. As you can see in my code, you pass the function as the argument to the apply method. In my case, I use a lambda function to define the function in the same expression, but you could just aswell define the function explicitly outside:

```
def get_city(code):
    return nomi.query_postal_code(code)['place_name']

df['City1'] = df['Postalcodestring'].apply(get_city)
```

Just on a sidenote: Don't get confused because my code doesn't use loops. Of course loops are needed to perform such an operation on multiple rows. It's just that `df.apply` does the looping internally, so you don't need to do it yourself.